# Closed kernel in a compact group is open

Tags: compactness, topological-groups

The way I think it *should* work is that
$${\rm ker} = \bigcap_{g \notin {\rm ker}} (G - g\,{\rm ker}),$$
with each $G - g\,{\rm ker}$ open.  Since $G$ is compact, there *should*, in fact, only be finitely many distinct $G - g\,{\rm ker}$ so that the intersection is open.  For some reason, I can't get all of the pieces to fit together.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is false, there are compact groups with infinite index closed, normal subgroups (open implies finite index, so this is why it contradicts your statement), and all kernels are normal subgroups.

Answer (score 0):

Compactness gives you the finiteness of *covers*. For any group $G$, and any proper subgroup $K$, if $gK \neq hK$ then $gK \cap hK = \emptyset$. So the cover $\{G -  gK : g \in G\}$ has an obvious finite subcover:

$$(G - gK) \cup (G - hK)  = G - (gK \cap hK) = G$$

But to get the intersection you wrote to be just $K$ (in particular, your kernel) you need to insure you took it over all $g \notin \ker$ or at least one representative for each coset. So the actual condition you need is that $K$ is of finite index in $G$, a purely algebraic condition.